# Understanding the stack address manipulation

Tags: c

> Consider the following piece of code (on a 32-bit Intel/Linux system):
>
> ```
> struct mystruct {
>   char a;
>   int b;
>   short c;
>   char d;
> };
> int main()
> {
>   struct mystruct foo[3];
>   char ch;
>   int i;
>
>   printf("%p %p %p %p %p\n", &foo[0], &foo[1], &foo[2], &ch, &i);
>
>   return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> Which of the following would be the most likely candidate for its output?
>
> 1. `0xfeeece90 0xfeeece9c 0xfeeecea8 0xfeeece8f 0xfeeece88`
> 2. `0xfeeece90 0xfeeece9c 0xfeeecea8 0xfeeeceb4 0xfeeeceb8`
> 3. `0xfeeece90 0xfeeece9c 0xfeeecea8 0xfeeeceb4 0xfeeeceb5`
> 4. `0xfeeece90 0xfeeece9c 0xfeeecea8 0xfeeece8c 0xfeeece88`

The output is option (1). I could not understand, how the option a is the right answer..

Stack grows from higher addresses to lower addresses. Here `foo[3]`, `foo[2]`, `foo[1]`, `foo[0]`, `ch`, `i` ... `i` will be at the lower address of stack and `foo[3]` at the higher address. Here the `sizeof(mystruct)` is 16, hence the `foo[3]`, `foo[2]`, `foo[1]`, `ch` will be laid with the address gap of 16.

I couldn't get the address difference 16 here with the below address:

```
0xfeeece90 0xfeeece9c 0xfeeecea8 0xfeeece8f 0xfeeece88
```

Comment: You just have to remember in which direction that stack grows, and the relative `sizeof` relationship between the various integral types in the question. And to account for struct padding due to alignment.

Comment: Here the `sizeof(mystruct)` is 16 - did you check this?

Comment: using `printf("%p"` is one of few cases where you actually _should_ cast pointers to `void *`. the representation of an `int *` or a `struct mystruct *` can be different to that of a `void *`. Failing to cast could trigger UB

Answer (score 4):

The options that are given to you suppose a `sizeof(mystruct)` of 12 bytes, which is plausible, since you'll have

- `a` at offset 0
- 3 bytes of padding to keep `b` aligned to 4 bytes
- `b` at offset 4
- `c` at offset 8 (no padding required, we are already at a multiple of 2)
- `d` at offset 10 (no padding required, `char` does not need any particular alignment)
- 1 byte of padding to keep the next element of an array on 4 bytes boundaries (so that the `b` of all elements remains aligned to 4 bytes boundaries).

So, all the options are plausible in this respect; next comes `ch`; assuming that the compiler keeps the order of variables (which is definitely *not* plausible in optimized builds) will sit right over `foo`. `foo` starts at `0xfeeece90` and `ch` does not have alignment requirements, so it'll be `0xfeeece8f`. Finally, `i` will sit at the nearest 4-bytes boundary above `ch`, which is indeed `0xfeeece88`.

Again: this discussion is realistic as far *as the `struct` is concerned*, it is not when talking about the locals. In an optimized build the order of declaration does not matter, the  compiler will probably reorder them to avoid wastes of space (and, if you do not ask for their address, will try to fit them in registers).

Comment: Why cant it be the last option `0xfeeece90 0xfeeece9c 0xfeeecea8 0xfeeece8c 0xfeeece88`

Comment: @Angus: because `c` is a char, and does not need to be aligned to 4 bytes boundaries.

Comment: @Angus: sorry, I messed up some names in the final part of the answer (and in the last comment I meant `ch`); check if now it makes more sense.